# I have 3 users on my computer. The internet works on 2 of them but not the third. How can this problem be sloved?

Tags: windows-vista, networking, internet

I have 3 users on my computer. The internet works on 2 of them but not the third. Downloading Firefox did not work. What should I do?

Comment: Citation needed \ MOAR INFO. :)

Answer (score 2):

There could be multiple reasons why this is happening.  There should be a basic troubleshooting scheme that will help you get the correct answer.  Was Internet Explorer the first browser you tried and this happened in?  Have you tried Chrome or other browsers with the same trouble?

On the user that the internet isn't working (i.e., logged in as that user), go to the Control Panel and then open up the Networking Connections window.  Take a look at the current connections.  Are they connected?  Do you see LAN or Internet in the list, among other items?  Double click the LAN icon and see if there is traffic.

If there is traffic, then you may have a browser issue.  If this is not showing packet transfer or seems disabled, go to the the Control Panel again and double click System and click the Hardware tab and then the Device Manager button.

Find in this list the Network Adapters and double click.  Be sure this is enabled for this user.  If it is, then go back and try the Internet again and see what happens.  If it's not, enable it and try the browser again.

If none of this works, I would consider backing up the user data and, if possible, create a new user account, test for Internet connection and then convert the user to that account.  This can be done relatively painlessly in Windows.

It really depends on how much work you want to do to fix this problem:  a whole bunch of troubleshooting or create a new account.

Comment: You don't necessarily need to migrate to a new account; you can probably just rename their profile folder and let Windows create a new one next time they log in.